# Is it possible to pass kwargs to the after() function in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, timer

I cannot find anything on google and I know that the syntax is `after(delay_ms, callback=None, *args)`, so in a way already kinda know the answer... but anyway, I was wondering if it was possible to pass also *kwargs into it, and how. I mean something like this:

```
frame.after(1000, button1.pack, side='left', fill='y')
```

For example, in the script below, can I rewrite it so that I don't have to define the `respawn` function myself, and simply call the `btn.pack` method in the `after()`?

```
import tkinter as tk


def click(*args):
    btn.pack_forget()
    btn.after(1000, btn_respawn, tk.RIGHT, tk.Y)


def btn_respawn(side, fill):
    btn.pack(side=side, fill=fill)


root = tk.Tk()
frame = tk.Frame(root, width=300, height=100, bg='orange')
btn = tk.Button(frame, text="test button", font=("Consolas", 14))

frame.pack_propagate(0)
frame.pack()
btn.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.Y)
btn.bind("<Button-1>", click)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `after()` it is really buggy

Comment: What should I use instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `functools.partial`

```
frame.after(1000, functools.update_wrapper(
    functools.partial(btn.pack, side='left', fill='y'), btn.pack))
```

This essentially creates your `btn_respawn` function for you.

Note you have to use `update_wrapper` to copy metadata (eg. `__name__`) from the original function to the partial.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the lambda statement.

```
frame.after(1000, lambda: button1.pack(side='left', fill='y'))
```

Comment: Does this work for dynamic parameter values, or only static/literal ones?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a dictionary as the third argument to after(), with key : value pairs containing the names and values of the keyword arguments you wish to pass to the underlying callback function.

```
btn.after(1000, btn.pack, {'side': 'left', 'fill': 'y'})
```